# Javascript Button onclick issue

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script>
function formSubmit()
$('#newhtml').html('hello world');
</script>

</head>
<body>
First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Search Data">
<div id="newhtml"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the code above, I try click the button which execute formSubmit() function on click and my div newhtml does not change to hello world.

Is there anything wrong with the code above..

Thanks!

Comment: your function is not correctly, it's not enclosed in braces.

Comment: Why are there 2 different versions of jQuery in you code. And why are you using jQuery to print Hello World???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#input").click(function(){
    $('#newhtml').html('hello world');

    })


    });

    </script>
```

HTML Code

```
<body>
First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
<input type="button" id="input" value="Search Data">
<div id="newhtml"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @user1777711 this answer is used jqury

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets to your function

```
function formSubmit() {
    $('#newhtml').html('hello world');
}
```

Comment: @user1777711 What amazing....lol. the Bracket is more important and how can u miss it......

Answer (score 0):

Your format for JavaScript function is wrong, wrap them in brackets

```
function formSubmit(){
    $('#newhtml').html('hello world');
}
```

Also, you don't have to include two different version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <head>

    <script>

      function formSubmit()
      {

          document.getElementById("newhtml").innerHTML="hello world";
      }
    </script>

</head>
<body>`enter code here`
    First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
   <input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Search Data">
  <div id="newhtml"></div>
```

Comment: @user1021726: rightly said. a small mistake can make ur project haywire.